# How can I get date like this in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I have a table with this data in SQL Server 2012.

`tbl_contract`:

```
ContractId         RenueDate          BillDay          BillMonth
------------------------------------------------------------------
     1             2014-06-15            10               -1
     2             2014-08-04             1               -2
```

Now I need to format a billing date and billing date should be according to billmonth and billday from renuedate, like,

```
 ContractId         RenueDate          BillingDate
---------------------------------------------------
     1             2014-06-15            2014-05-10        
     2             2014-08-04            2014-06-01
```

and I need to do it with a SQL query only. Means I need to get those contract whose billing date is less or equal to today's date. And I need to create billing date from renue date, billday and billmonth.

Can anyone help me to do this? What should I do in query to format billing date and compare it to today's date like this ?

Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for dateAdd() ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select
    ContractId, 
    RenueDate,
    BillingDate = Cast(DateAdd(month, BillMonth, DateAdd(day,BillDay-1,DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, RenueDate), 0))) as date)
from tbl_contract
```

Test:

```
select
    ContractId, 
    RenueDate,
    BillingDate = Cast(DateAdd(month, BillMonth, DateAdd(day,BillDay-1,DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, RenueDate), 0))) as date)
from
(
    values 
    (1, cast('2014-06-15' as date), 10, -1),
    (2, cast('2014-08-04' as date), 1, -2)
) as tbl_contract(ContractId, RenueDate, BillDay, BillMonth)
```

Comment: @runfanov : thanks but i am getting NULL billingdate.

Comment: hey actually i don't need to add billday to date but i need billday as day in date. like if billday is 10 than i need 10th as day.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CONTRACTID, RENUEDATE, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(D,-(DAY(NEWDATE)) + BillDay,NEWDATE),111),'/','-')
From (
Select CONTRACTID, 
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,RENUEDATE,111),'/','-') RENUEDATE, DATEADD(M, BILLMONTH, RENUEDATE) NEWDATE, BillDay
From TBL_CONTRACT
) AS Tbl
```

try this one. it's give you output same as you given.
as below.

```
CONTRACTID     RENUEDATE    BILLINGDATE
1              2014-06-15      2014-05-10
2              2014-08-04       2014-06-01
```

Comment: @VigneshKumar, i update query check in now. let me know if any problm.

Comment: @RiteshKhatri Yes fine...+1